# How to crop white patches in image and make passport size photo using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have images that need to be cropped to perfect passport size photos. I have thousands of images that need to be cropped and straightened automatically like this. If the image is too blur and not able to crop I need it to be copied to the rejected folder. I tried to do using haar cascade but this approach is giving me only face. But I need a face with a photo-cropped background. Can anyone tell me how I can code this in OpenCV or any?

```
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(
                cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
            faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
                gray,
                scaleFactor=1.3,
                minNeighbors=3,
                minSize=(30, 30)
            )
            if(len(faces) == 1):
                for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                    if(x-w < 100 and y-h < 100):
                        ystart = int(y-y*int(y1)/100)
                        xstart = int(x-x*int(x1)/100)
                        yend = int(h+h*int(y1)/100)
                        xend = int(w+w*int(y2)/100)
                        roi_color = img[ystart:y + yend, xstart:x + xend]
                        cv2.imwrite(path, roi_color)

                    else:
                        rejectedCount += 1
                        cv2.imwrite(path, img)
```

**Before**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**After**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all photos have that thin white-black border around them, you can just

0. threshold the pictures
1. get all contours and
2. select those contours that

   - have the correct gradient
   - are large enough
   - that reduce to 4 corners when passed through `approxPolyDP`
3. get an oriented bounding box
4. construct affine transformation
5. apply affine transformation

If those photos aren't scans but taken with a camera *from an angle* (not top-down), you'll need to use a perspective transformation calculated from the corner points themselves.

If the photos aren't flat but warped, that's an entirely different problem.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

im = cv.imread("Zh8QV.jpg")
gray = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray = 255 - gray # invert so findContours' implicit black border doesn't bother us

height, width = gray.shape
minarea = (height * width) * 0.20

# (th_level, thresholded) = cv.threshold(gray, thresh=128, maxval=255, type=cv.THRESH_OTSU)

# threshold relative to estimated brightness of "white"
th_level = 255 - (255 - np.median(gray)) * 0.98
(th_level, thresholded) = cv.threshold(gray, thresh=th_level, maxval=255, type=cv.THRESH_BINARY)

(contours, hierarchy) = cv.findContours(thresholded, mode=cv.RETR_LIST, method=cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# black-to-white contours have negative area...
#areas = sorted([cv.contourArea(c, oriented=True) for c in contours])

large_areas = [ c for c in contours if cv.contourArea(c, oriented=True) <= -minarea ]

quads = [
    c for c in large_areas
    if len(cv.approxPolyDP(c, epsilon=0.02 * cv.arcLength(c, True), closed=True)) == 4
]

# if there is no quad, or multiple, that's an error (for this example)
assert len(quads) == 1, quads
[quad] = quads

bbox = cv.minAreaRect(quad)
(bcenter, bsize, bangle) = bbox
bcenter = np.array(bcenter)
bsize = np.array(bsize)

# keep orientation upright, fix up bbox size
(rot90, bangle) = divmod(bangle + 45, 90)
bangle -= 45
if rot90 % 2 != 0:
    bsize = bsize[::-1]

# construct affine transformation
M1 = np.eye(3)
M1[0:2,2] = -bcenter

R = np.eye(3)
R[0:2] = cv.getRotationMatrix2D(center=(0,0), angle=bangle, scale=1.0)

M2 = np.eye(3)
M2[0:2,2] = +bsize * 0.5

M = M2 @ R @ M1

bwidth, bheight = np.ceil(bsize)
dsize = (int(bwidth), int(bheight))

output = cv.warpAffine(im, M[0:2], dsize=dsize, flags=cv.INTER_CUBIC)

cv.imshow("output", output)
cv.waitKey(-1)
cv.destroyWindow("output")
```

[image: input]
[image: output]

Comment: Bro the code is not showing output image https://imgur.com/zzQ731c

Comment: When I put the whole code inside the try-catch block it's giving me an error. Can you fix the code?

Comment: can you tell me what picture you used?

Comment: I used the same picture that you have used

Comment: thank you for pointing out the issue. it is fixed and the answer is updated.

Comment: Your code working for the given image. But if the image has little bit of shadow it's doesn't work. https://imgur.com/YWHEvww

Comment: Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: correct, I assumed that pictures are framed by a black border. when they aren't, this can fail. it could be fixed by choosing a threshold close to white... which requires estimating the brightness of "white" of the image. I see that your images have strongly varying quality. since the scope of this question appears to widen progressively, I will stop investing time now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236545/discussion-between-harshith-va-and-christoph-rackwitz).

Answer (score 7):

I will handle your problem as follows:

1. First of all we need to grab the points which we are interested in
2. Know the size of a normal passport avatar in pixels

##### How to grab the points of interest.

We have more methods:

1. You can use `windows` paint application
2. But to be more programmatic we can use `cv2`. I'm going to show you how to do that using cv2.

> Also note that this does not yield a high resolution image, you have to play around the code yourself.

```
# imports 
import numpy as np
import cv2

width = height = 600 # normal passport photo size in pixels

# global variable that will update the points when we clicked on the image
pt1 = []
pt2 = np.float32([[0, 0], [height, 0], [0, width], [height, width]])
def mouseEvent(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        global pt1
        if len(pt1) == 4:
            pt1 = []
        else:
            pt1.append([x, y])

while 1:
    image = cv2.imread("img.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    cv2.imshow("Original Image", image)
    cv2.setMouseCallback("Original Image", mouseEvent)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    if len(pt1) == 4:
        break
```

Then we use two `cv2` functions which are `getPerspectiveTransform` and `warpPerspective`. The `getPerspectiveTransform()` will accept two points which our `pt1` and `pt2` then we are going to call the `warpPerspective()` function and pass three positional args, the image, the matrix and the image shape:

```py
image = cv2.imread("img.jpg", 0)
matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(np.float32(pt1), pt2)
image = cv2.warpPerspective(image, matrix, image.shape)
cv2.imshow("Wrap Perspective", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I know this is not a good explanation but you get the idea. The whole code program will look as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

width = height = 600 # normal passport photo size in pixels
pt1 = []
pt2 = np.float32([[0, 0], [height, 0], [0, width], [height, width]])
def mouseEvent(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        global pt1
        if len(pt1) == 4:
            pt1 = []
        else:
            pt1.append([x, y])
while 1:
    image = cv2.imread("img.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    cv2.imshow("Original Image", image)
    cv2.setMouseCallback("Original Image", mouseEvent)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    if len(pt1) == 4:
        break

image = cv2.imread("img.jpg", 0)
matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(np.float32(pt1), pt2)
image = cv2.warpPerspective(image, matrix, image.shape)
cv2.imshow("Wrap Perspective", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

1. When you run the following code then an image will be shown.
2. To use this program you have to click four points in order from `A-D`. for example if this is your image:

```
------------------
| (a)          (b)|
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
| (c)          (d)|
-------------------
```

Where a, b, c and d are the points you are interested in on your image `crop`.

##### Demo

[image]

Click point `1` then `2` then `3` and lastly `4` to get the results above

Comment: I have 10000+ images which needs be cropped. I don't I think manually doing it using mouse is not a feasible idea. Is there a way to auto detect points?

Comment: You can use artificial intelligence, or `cascadeClassifiers` which is the better way of doing it

Comment: "use AI" is a non-answer (equivalent to "use magic") and cascade classifiers are totally unsuitable to pick those corner points because those corner points occur with some rotation. cascade classifiers are known to fail when things are rotated.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way to extract the photo in Python/OpenCV by keying on the black lines surrounding the image.

Input:

[image]

```
 - Read the input
 - Pad the image with white so that the lines can be extended until intersection
 - Threshold on black to extract the lines
 - Apply morphology close to try to connect the lines somewhat
 - Get the contours and filter on area drawing the contours on a black background
 - Apply morphology close again to fill the line centers
 - Skeletonize to thin the lines
 - Get the Hough lines and draw them as white on a black background
 - Floodfill the center of the rectangle of lines to fill with mid-gray. Then convert that image to binary so that the gray becomes white and all else is black.
 - Get the coordinates of all non-black pixels and then from the coordinates get the rotated rectangle.
 - Use the angle and center of the rotated rectangle to unrotated both the padded image and this mask image via an Affine warp
 - (Alternately, get the four corners of the rotated rectangle from the mask and then project that to the padded input domain using the affine matrix)
- Get the coordinates of all non-black pixels in the unrotated mask and compute its rotated rectangle.
 - Get the bounding box of the (un-)rotated rectangle 
 - Use those bounds to crop the padded image
 - Save the results

import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize

# read image
img = cv2.imread('passport.jpg')
ht, wd = img.shape[:2]

# pad image with white by 20% on all sides
padpct = 20
xpad = int(wd*padpct/100)
ypad = int(ht*padpct/100)
imgpad = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img, ypad, ypad, xpad, xpad, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=(255,255,255))
ht2, wd2 = imgpad.shape[:2]

# threshold on black
low = (0,0,0)
high = (20,20,20)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.inRange(imgpad, low, high)

# apply morphology to connect the white lines
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get contours
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

# filter on area
mask = np.zeros((ht2,wd2), dtype=np.uint8)
for cntr in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cntr)
    if area > 20:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [cntr], 0, 255, 1)

# apply morphology to connect the white lines and divide by 255 to make image in range 0 to 1
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
bmask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)/255

# apply thinning (skeletonizing)
skeleton = skeletonize(bmask)
skeleton = (255*skeleton).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# get hough lines
line_img = np.zeros_like(imgpad, dtype=np.uint8)
lines= cv2.HoughLines(skeleton, 1, math.pi/180.0, 90, np.array([]), 0, 0)
a,b,c = lines.shape
for i in range(a):
    rho = lines[i][0][0]
    theta = lines[i][0][1]
    a = math.cos(theta)
    b = math.sin(theta)
    x0, y0 = a*rho, b*rho
    pt1 = ( int(x0+1000*(-b)), int(y0+1000*(a)) )
    pt2 = ( int(x0-1000*(-b)), int(y0-1000*(a)) )
    cv2.line(line_img, pt1, pt2, (255, 255, 255), 1)

# floodfill with mid-gray (128)
xcent = int(wd2/2)
ycent = int(ht2/2)
ffmask = np.zeros((ht2+2, wd2+2), np.uint8)
mask2 = line_img.copy()
mask2 = cv2.floodFill(mask2, ffmask, (xcent,ycent), (128,128,128))[1]

# convert mask2 to binary
mask2[mask2 != 128] = 0
mask2[mask2 == 128] = 255
mask2 = mask2[:,:,0]

# get coordinates of all non-zero pixels
# NOTE: must transpose since numpy coords are y,x and opencv uses x,y
coords = np.column_stack(np.where(mask2.transpose() > 0))

# get rotated rectangle from coords
rotrect = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)
(center), (width,height), angle = rotrect
# from https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/20/text-skew-correction-opencv-python/
# the `cv2.minAreaRect` function returns values in the
# range [-90, 0); as the rectangle rotates clockwise the
# returned angle trends to 0 -- in this special case we
# need to add 90 degrees to the angle
if angle < -45:
    angle = -(90 + angle)
 
# otherwise, just take the inverse of the angle to make
# it positive
else:
    angle = -angle

# compute correction rotation
rotation = -angle - 90

# compute rotation affine matrix
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, rotation, scale=1.0)
    
# unrotate imgpad and mask2 using affine warp
rot_img = cv2.warpAffine(imgpad, M, (wd2, ht2), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderValue=(0,0,0))
rot_mask2= cv2.warpAffine(mask2, M, (wd2, ht2), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderValue=(0,0,0))

# get coordinates of all non-zero pixels
# NOTE: must transpose since numpy coords are y,x and opencv uses x,y
coords2 = np.column_stack(np.where(rot_mask2.transpose() > 0))

# get bounding box
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(coords2)
print(x,y,w,h)

# crop rot_img
result = rot_img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

# save resulting images
cv2.imwrite('passport_pad.jpg',imgpad)
cv2.imwrite('passport_thresh.jpg',thresh)
cv2.imwrite('passport_morph.jpg',morph)
cv2.imwrite('passport_mask.jpg',mask)
cv2.imwrite('passport_skeleton.jpg',skeleton)
cv2.imwrite('passport_line_img.jpg',line_img)
cv2.imwrite('passport_mask2.jpg',mask2)
cv2.imwrite('passport_rot_img.jpg',rot_img)
cv2.imwrite('passport_rot_mask2.jpg',rot_mask2)
cv2.imwrite('passport_result.jpg',result)

# show thresh and result    
cv2.imshow("imgpad", imgpad)
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("morph", morph)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("skeleton", skeleton)
cv2.imshow("line_img", line_img)
cv2.imshow("mask2", mask2)
cv2.imshow("rot_img", rot_img)
cv2.imshow("rot_mask2", rot_mask2)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Padded Image:

[image]

Threshold Image:

[image]

Morphology cleaned Image:

[image]

Mask1 Image:

[image]

Skeleton Image:

[image]

(Hough) Line Image:

[image]

Floodfilled Line Image - Mask2:

[image]

Unrotated Padded Image:

[image]

Unrotated Mask2 Image:

[image]

Cropped Image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried this code but it's working only for this image. It's not working for other images. I have added two more images in question please check. Let me know the changes I need to do in the code.

Comment: Very difficult to make it work for all images. The black lines are not prominent or dark enough in all your images. You also have extraneous black lines at the time of one image. Also the images are warped so that the black lines are not straight, so the Hough lines will not detect a single line, but multiple lines for each side.

Answer (score 3):

What I would do is the following 3 steps (I'm not going to code it for you, sorry, if you need help with one of the stages I'll be happy to help):

1. Use `Hough transform` to detect the 4 strongest lines in the picture.
2. Compute the 4 intersection points of the lines
3. Apply perspective transformation.

And you should have the cropped image as desired.

Answer (score 2):

#### The Concept

1. Process each image to enhance the edges of the photos.
2. Get the 4 corners of the photo of each processed image by first finding the contour with the greatest area, getting its convex hull and approximating the convex hull until only 4 points are left.
3. Warp each image according to the 4 corners detected.

#### The Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def process(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (1, 1), 1)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_blur, 350, 150)
    kernel = np.ones((3, 3))
    img_dilate = cv2.dilate(img_canny, kernel, iterations=2)
    return cv2.erode(img_dilate, kernel, iterations=1)

def get_pts(img):
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
    peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
    return cv2.approxPolyDP(cv2.convexHull(cnt), 0.04 * peri, True)

files = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]
width, height = 350, 450
pts2 = np.float32([[width, 0], [0, 0], [width, height], [0, height]])

for file in files:
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    pts1 = get_pts(process(img)).squeeze()
    pts1 = np.float32(pts1[np.lexsort(pts1.T)])
    matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1, pts2)
    out = cv2.warpPerspective(img, matrix, (width, height))[5:-5, 5:-5]
    cv2.imshow(file, out)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

#### The Output

I placed each output next to each others to fit in one image:

[image]

#### The Explanation

1. Import the necessary libraries:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
```

2. Define a function, `process()`, that takes in a BGR image array and returns the image processed with the [Canny edge detector](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html) for more accurate detection of the edges of each photo later. The values used in the function can be tweaked to be more suitable for other images if needed:

```
def process(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (1, 1), 1)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_blur, 350, 150)
    kernel = np.ones((3, 3))
    img_dilate = cv2.dilate(img_canny, kernel, iterations=2)
    return cv2.erode(img_dilate, kernel, iterations=1)
```

3. Define a function, `get_pts()`, that takes in a processed image and returns 4 points of the convex hull of the contour with the greatest area. In order to get 4 points out of the convex hull, we use the [`cv2.approxPolyDP()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga0012a5fdaea70b8a9970165d98722b4c) method:

```
def get_pts(img):
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
    peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
    return cv2.approxPolyDP(cv2.convexHull(cnt), 0.04 * peri, True)
```

4. Define a list, `files` containing the names of each file you want to extract the photos from, and the dimensions you want the resulting images to be, `width` and `height`:

```
files = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]
width, height = 350, 450
```

5. Using the dimensions defined above, define a matrix for each of the 4 soon-to-be detected coordinated to be mapped to:

```
pts2 = np.float32([[width, 0], [0, 0], [width, height], [0, height]])
```

6. Loop through each filename, read each the file into a BGR image array, get the 4 points of the photo within the image, use the [`cv2.getPerspectiveTransform()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga20f62aa3235d869c9956436c870893ae) method to get the solution matrix for the warping, and finally warp the photo portion of the image with the solution matrices using the [cv2.warpPerspective()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87) method:

```
for file in files:
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    pts1 = get_pts(process(img)).squeeze()
    pts1 = np.float32(pts1[np.lexsort(pts1.T)])
    matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1, pts2)
    out = cv2.warpPerspective(img, matrix, (width, height))[5:-5, 5:-5]
    cv2.imshow(file, out)
```

7. Finally, add a delay and after that destroy all the windows:

```
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```